# Android making multiple flavors due to layout changes.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

At the moment i have multiple repositories containing 50% shared code (Mostly business logic). Each repository has slight tweaks to all layers of MVP (activities, presenter, business logic).

I'm wanting to put all of my repositories into one, though i'm unsure how to go about this nicely.

My current thought process is to create multiple build flavors, so each flavor will load up different components. I looked up into build flavors and they recommended it for "Text Changes" and "Color Changes", however i'm doing a bit more than that.

Would this be considered bad practice to also swap out activies,presenters and some business logic?

What would be an alternative solution? so far I haven't found someone that knows the answer to this question (even asking professionals).

Comment: Using flavours you can do it, flavours are not used only for text or color changes, you can even specify your buissnes logic as well. watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDEK4wkN5I

Answer (score 0):

You can use flavors to do what you need.

You can create separate java sourcesets and resource files for each flavour, but you need to place them in the respective flavor's directory.

You can write separate business logic for and also have various UIs for different flavors.

Moreover, the main purpose of using flavors is to have multiple versions of the same app with different features.